# pagination_marker

Tags: pagination

When viewing a single entry in the category I am using pagination to view the second entry
http://domain.ca/index.php/showroom/category/CATEGORY_NAME

Next goes to 
http://domain.ca/index.php/showroom/category/CATEGORY_NAME/P1 and so on.

But If I view the same page with an entry url:
http://domain.ca/index.php/showroom/url_title
My pagination switches to: {pagination_marker}

I have pagination="inline"

How do I get pagination to work both on a /P1 page as well as a url_title page?

I want to be able to display a single entry at a time with a link to go to next / previous.  using a single template if I am viewing a category or a single url_title entry

Comment: Could you share some code - that would help.

Comment: [code]
{exp:channel:entries channel="portfolio" dynamic="yes" paginate="inline" limit="1" status="not Closed"}
{title}
{paginate}
{if previous_page}
<a href="{auto_path}"><</a>
{/if}
|
{if next_page}
<a href="{auto_path}">></a>
{/if}
{/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}[/code]

Comment: hope that helps.

If I am viewing a category page I want to display one entry at a time with a link to go prev and next

And using the same template I want the same pagination to work if I am viewing a single entry

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just using http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/next-previous-links-anywhere seemed to work just great for me in this case